# Align image and text in Outlook

Tags: html, responsive-design, outlook

I can't find a solution to this problem. I need to align some text and an image but can't use a table, since the HTML should also have some responsive behavior (see images below). Any ideas how to solve this?

Normal Display:

[image: Normal Display]

Mobile display:

[image: Mobile Display]

Answer (score -1):

Great! Just figured out the solution after posting the question, but maybe it will be helpful to someone else:

The solution is two separate tables, one for the image and one for the text, both with align="left". I had the image "naked" in there before, that pushed the table with the text under the image.

Comment: the solution uses table